# How to determine if a point is within an polygon consist of horizontal and vertical lines only?

Tags: computer-vision, geometry, computational-geometry

I want to find a best way because all coordinates are integer values and polygons consist of horizontal and vertical lines only. I think there may be a simple and fast method to do this.

Comment: Specify usage: one point and one polygon; many points vs one polygon; one point for many polygons?

Answer (score 0):

From an asymptotic complexity point of view, a rectilinear polygon is not really simpler to process than a general one: O(N) without preprocessing, and O(Log N) after O(N Log N) preprocessing (but using a complicated procedure).

For the case of no preprocessing, the procedure is simple: consider every vertical side in turn and count those that cross the horizontal half-line from the given point (+1 upward, -1 downward). The point is inside if the final count is nonzero.

[image]

The status of points on the outline is application-dependent.

---

For rectilinear poygons with not too large integer coordinates, you can anyway do a little better, by "compressing" them. By two independent sorts on X and Y, you can obtain a mapping from X (or Y) to integer indexes in range [0,N). This gives the shrunk polygon below, of size NxN.

[image]

Now you can embed the polygon in an image and preprocess to label the pixels as inside/outside (by seed-filling). After filling two lookup-tables for coordinate conversion, you can obtain the status of any point in constant time O(1).

This will take O(N²+M) preprocessing time and storage, where M is the range of X and Y values.

Answer (score -1):

Consider any polygon, not necessary convex, formed only with horizontal and vetical lines:
[image]

Take a point (I've drawn A,B,C,D) and draw horizontal and vertical lines passing through the point.

Let's take point `A`. You see the horizontal line through it crosses four (vertical) segments. Note one segment is at left and the others are at right.

For point `B` its horizontal line crosses also four segments, but two at left and two at right.

The conditions that a point must fulfill to be inside a polygon are:

- At least one segment is horizontaly crossed at left of the point.
- At least one segment is horizontaly crossed at right of the point.
- Both numbers of crosses `left, right` must be odd.

Same three conditions for vertical lines.

So, in pseudocode it goes like this:

```
let nL = 0, nR = 0 //left/right counters
let nA = 0, nU = 0 //above/under counters

for each segment s(sx1,sy1, sx2, sy2) in polygon
    if point is on segment
        return true //or false, your choice
    else if segment is vertical and pointY is inside of (sy1,sy2)
        if pointX > min(sx1,sx2)
            nL = nL + 1
        else
            nR = nR + 1
    else if segment is horizontal and pointX is inside of (sx1,sx2)
        if pointY > min(sy1,sy2)
            nU = nU + 1
        else
            nA = nA + 1

//Check conditions
if nL > 0 and nR > 0 and nL is odd and nR is odd
    return true
if nA > 0 and nU > 0 and nA is odd and nU is odd
    return true
return false
```